# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER

Tags: case

```
SELECT CASE WHEN no > 1 THEN name ELSE 3 END FROM test
```

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER

I am getting the above error.  How can I use a `varchar` column in this case?

Comment: So make it consistent..?

Comment: Please feel free to use [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

Put the number in quotes to make it a `varchar`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN no > 1 THEN name ELSE '3' END
FROM test
```